# Form submit session value on textbox

Tags: php

I have a problem here saving a value on a textbox using session.

I enter a value on one of the textbox and the other one has none, I submit it. The value will come out on the first textbox and will disable the textbox, but when i put a value on the second textbox and submit it, the value on the first textbox has gone. Can anyone help me with this problem?

**PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
@$two = $_POST['two'];
@$four = $_POST['four'];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_SESSION['two'] = $two;
    $_SESSION['four'] = $four;
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST">
Textbox One:  <input type="text" value="<?=@$_SESSION['two']; ?>" name="two" class="inputborder" size="20" <?phpif(@$_SESSION['two']){ echo"disabled=disabled";} else{echo ""; }?> />
<br>    
Textbox Two:  <input type="text" value="<?=@$_SESSION['four']; ?>" name="four" class="inputborder" size="20" <?php if(@$_SESSION['four']){ echo"disabled=disabled";}else{ echo ""; }?> />
<br>        
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Start by removing the `@` symbols. These are suppressing errors

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to grab the variables for $two and $four before checking submit?

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  if(isset($_POST['two'])){
      $two = $_POST['two'];
  }

  if(isset($_POST['four'])){
      $four = $_POST['four'];
  }

   $_SESSION['two'] = $two;
   $_SESSION['four'] = $four;
}
?>
```

That should remove the need for the '@' symbol in the PHP. (although further error handling would be appropriate). But you are suppressing errors everywhere, how are you supposed to get feedback?